# How to create a grading calculator that takes only positive integers and gives out errors if the user doesn't include whole positive integers

Tags: javascript, error-handling, calculator

This is the javascript that I've got so far. It gives me an error in any text box I put anything else but an integer, but still calculates the rest of the other numbers.

```
        function finalGrade(number) {

            //set a default value for this just to create the variable 
            var numberOrder = ''; 

            //test the number and create a message string to return
            if (number >= 90.00) {
                numberOrder = 'A';
            } else if (number <= 89.99) {
                numberOrder = 'B';
            } else if (number <=79.99){
                numberOrder = 'C';
            }
              else if (number <=69.99){
                  numberOrder = 'D';
              }
              else if (number <=59.99){
                numberOrder = 'F';
            }

            return numberOrder;
        }   

        function calculateNumbers() {
            //this will get the text from the text box
            var number1 = document.getElementById('text-box-1').value;
            /* this will print to the console
             this is for debugging, not for the end user */
            console.log("The text in text-box-1 is: " + number1);

            /* these next two lines turn will do the same as
              the previous two lines for box 1*/
            var number2 = document.getElementById('text-box-2').value;
            console.log("The text in text-box-2 is: " + number2);

            //this is text box 3
            var number3 = document.getElementById('text-box-3').value;
            console.log("The text in text-box-3 is: " + number3);

            //this is text box 4
            var number4 = document.getElementById('text-box-4').value;
            console.log("The text in text-box-4 is: " + number4);

            //this is text box 5
            var number5 = document.getElementById('text-box-5').value;
            console.log("The text in text-box-5 is: " + number5);


            //if the STRING number1 does not contain only digits    
            if (!stringIsNumbers(number1)) {
                //set and error message
                var message = "test score 1 is not a whole, positive 
    integer";
                //display the error in the console and to the page
                console.log(message);
                document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerHTML = message;
            } else if (!stringIsNumbers(number2)) {
                // testing the STRING number2 the same way
                var message = "test score 2 is not a whole, positive 
    integer";
                console.log(message);
                document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerHTML = message;
            } 
            else if (!stringIsNumbers(number3)) {
                // testing the STRING number3 the same way
                var message = "homework average is not a whole, positive 
    integer";
                console.log(message);
                document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerHTML = message;
            }
            else if (!stringIsNumbers(number4)) {
                // testing the STRING number4 the same way
                var message = "in-class average is not a whole, positive 
    integer";
                console.log(message);
                document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerHTML = message;
            }
            else if (!stringIsNumbers(number5)) {
                // testing the STRING number5 the same way
                var message = "final project is not a whole, positive 
    integer";
                console.log(message);
                document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerHTML = message;
            }

            else {

                //passed both tests, so now I can process the numbers


            /*these next four lines turn the text into numbers,
             but this won't work if the text does not represent a number*/
            number1 = parseInt(number1);
            number2 = parseInt(number2);
            number3 = parseInt(number3);
            number4 = parseInt(number4);
            number5 = parseInt(number5);

            var grade1 = (number1*0.15);
            var grade2 = (number2*0.15);
            var grade3 = (number3*0.40);
            var grade4 = (number4*0.20);
            var grade5 = (number5*0.10);


            //do the math and show it in the console
            result = grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5;
            console.log("The answer is: " + result.toFixed(2));


            //put the answer back into the Web page
            document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 
        result.toFixed(2);

            }
        }
    </script>
```

I want there to be an error after I press calculate as if the user input a negative integer, a word or phrase, or just anything else but a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

This should cut it. I've updated your code slightly to be a little bit more modern. Also, I've added the function `checkNumber` to check if the error message should be added.

```js
checkNumber = num => isNaN(num) || Number(num) <= 0;
finalGrade = number => {
  if (number >= 90.00) {
    return 'A';
  } else if (number <= 89.99) {
    return 'B';
  } else if (number <= 79.99) {
    return 'C';
  } else if (number <= 69.99) {
    return 'D';
  } else if (number <= 59.99) {
    return 'F';
  }
}

calculateNumbers = () => {
  let number1 = document.getElementById('text-box-1').innerText;
  let number2 = document.getElementById('text-box-2').innerText;
  let number3 = document.getElementById('text-box-3').innerText;
  let number4 = document.getElementById('text-box-4').innerText;
  let number5 = document.getElementById('text-box-5').innerText;

  if (checkNumber(number1)) {
    //set and error message
    let message = "test score 1 is not a whole, positive integer ";
    document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerText = message;
  } else if (checkNumber(number2)) {
    let message = "test score 2 is not a whole, positive integer ";
    document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerText = message;
  } else if (checkNumber(number3)) {
    let message = "homework average is not a whole, positive integer ";
    document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerText = message;
  } else if (checkNumber(number4)) {
    let message = "in-class average is not a whole, positive integer ";
    document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerText = message;
  } else if (checkNumber(number5)) {
    let message = "final project is not a whole, positive integer ";
    document.getElementById('answerLabel').innerText = message;
  } else {
    number1 = parseInt(number1);
    number2 = parseInt(number2);
    number3 = parseInt(number3);
    number4 = parseInt(number4);
    number5 = parseInt(number5);

    let grade1 = (number1 * 0.15);
    let grade2 = (number2 * 0.15);
    let grade3 = (number3 * 0.40);
    let grade4 = (number4 * 0.20);
    let grade5 = (number5 * 0.10);

    result = grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5;
    document.getElementById('answer').innerText = `${finalGrade(result)} (${result.toFixed(2)}/100)`;
  }
}
calculateNumbers();
```

```html
<div id="text-box-1">1</div>
<div id="text-box-2">2</div>
<div id="text-box-3">3</div>
<div id="text-box-4">4</div>
<div id="text-box-5">5</div>
<br/> Result:
<span id="answerLabel">successful</span>
<br/> Answer:
<span id="answer"></span>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: i do get a correct output but i want an error to come out if its not an actual number put into the answer section. also need a letter grade like (i.e.A,B,C,D,F) to be put next to the grade output